Running eslint npm script with yarn not working
I have set up an ESLint script in package.json that should check for linting errors:
    "lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx} package.json",

The problem I have is that when I run the command yarn lint from terminal, it always gives the same output, even when I have errors:
yarn run v1.22.19
$ eslint ./src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx} package.json
✨  Done in 18.39s.

But, if I run the command directly in terminal:
yarn eslint ./src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx} package.json

Then I get all the ESLint errors in the terminal.
Why is it not working when I run it as a script in terminal?

Probably you need to quote the path, otherwise the asterisk could be expanded by the shell.
